# Given two int numbers A and B. How to find next multiple of B that is not less than A?

Tags: c

Suppose you input A = 15, B = 6, The answer is 18. What algorithm do I need?

This is what I try, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a, b;

scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

for (  ; a % b != 0; a++ ) {
    if ( a % b == 0 ) {
        printf("%d\n", a);
        return a;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I get infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you first read `a` from the user, then overwrite it in the loop header?

Comment: ok, I just initiated some value, sorry

Comment: how can you find a multiple of A that is not greater than A ?

Comment: The multiple of A that is not greater than A? only A * 1.

Comment: Maybe it will help explaining better what exactly you want. To me, "the next multiple of A" is simply `2*A`. Obviously it's not as simple as that, because then you would not need a loop. What is the exact problem? (Also, I notice that you have done about a dozen edits already -- take a deep breath, think about it for 10 seconds, and then start writing, otherwise you risk people pressing the "vote down" button and moving on, when in fact your goal is to get a good answer.)

Comment: It should work like this: A = 15, B = 6, Next Multiple of B is 18

Comment: you might want to print out a and b before entering the loop. scanf is not the most user-friendly way of reading input and it's easy to go wrong. Also, returning 'a' isn't a very standard way of exiting

Comment: @user1838334 18 is definitely greater than 15, which disagrees with the way you've asked your question

Comment: if you wanted a multiple why are you doing a++, your question needs a lot of cleaning up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question (now) asks for:

> The next multiple of b that is not less than a?

Using your notation of `a` and `b`, you can write it directly like this:

```
int NextMultipleUp(int a, int b)
{
    int r = a % b;
    if (r == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return a + b - r;
}
```

---

The question originally asked for

> The next multiple of a that is not greater than b

And for that the answer is

```
int NextMultipleDown(int a, int b)
{
    return b - b % a;
}
```

This was the answer for which the original comments applied to.

Comment: Why do you calculate if the multiple of A that is not greater than A? only A * 1.

Comment: @mux no - try that with b=5 and a=2.

Comment: @mux, why would you assign the value `a` to a temporary evaluated to `b - b % a`????

Comment: @StephaneRolland not assigning, it's an equation

Comment: @mux of course, but in c++ you write it like that `b - b % a == a`

Comment: I cannot understand the downvote. Anyone care to explain it? Remember that the question changed!

Answer (score 1):

```
return (((a-1) / b )+1) * b;
```

Always returns a multiple of b.  Increment the integer dividend to get a multiple that is larger than the original a - subtract one from the original, because we want 'not less than' rather than 'greater than' a

Answer (score 0):

```
int nextMultiple(int a,int b)
{
  if(a%b == 0) return a;
  return a+(b-(a%b));
}
```

so if a=15 b=6

the ans is

```
=15+(6-(15%6))
=15+(6-(3))
=15+3
=18
```

Comment: Is 15 % 6 = 3? Isn't the remainder of division 15 / 6 is 5 (2,5)?

Comment: This fails when a is a multiple of b

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : since the OP asked for number > a not equal to a if multiple of b my answer is right

Comment: The question title states "not less than a". Which equates to ">=a". Where does he say "> a"? Did I miss that? Admittedly there have been so many different versions of the question.

Comment: yeah it was previously > i think he changed the question anyways updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a `do - while` iterative loop, so I will give an alternative answer.

> How to find next multiple of B that is not less than A?

Obviously this code is slower than David's.

```
int main ( void ){

    int a, b, c;
    long int result;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    c = 0;

    do {
        result = b * c;
        c++;
    } while ( result < a );

    printf( " The number is: %d \n", result );
}
```